# Mac Monterey Terminal restores itself after every restart

Tags: terminal, monterey, zsh

Not long ago I noticed that when I open zsh and enter  "last" it displays my login dates but now below each instance there is a gray bar with the text [Restored MONTH DAY, YEAR at TIME]

I do not know how this happened or how to make it stop,  and I'm unsure of the significance. Could someone please elucidate?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

macOS Terminal, or actually the shell running within Terminal, automatically restores its state when restarted, so you would see any previously run commands and their output etc.

The code for this is in `/etc/{bash,zsh}rc_Apple_Terminal`, in the default configuration it ensures that shell history is preserved even if you have several tabs open in Terminal.

Both files include details about configuration options and also explain how to disable it as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

In `Terminal.app`, click on `Profiles`. in the Tab `Window` for each profile is a section called *Resume*. Make sure that *Restore text when reopening windows* is unchecked. This applies at least for version 2.12 of Terminal.app.